# Set Team Iteration Security Settings with TfsSecurity in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I have a script that we are using to configure security in our on-premise TFS 2017 instance. We want to give the Contributors group access to change iteration info for a project (which normally only the Project Admins can do). I was able to accomplish giving them access to create new iterations under the Admin > Work > Iterations tab by running the following commands:

```
tfssecurity.exe /a+ Iteration $rootIterationUri CREATE_CHILDREN "n:[$projectName]\Contributors" ALLOW /collection:$collection
tfssecurity.exe /a+ Iteration $rootIterationUri DELETE "n:[$projectName]\Contributors" ALLOW /collection:$collection
tfssecurity.exe /a+ Iteration $rootIterationUri GENERIC_WRITE "n:[$projectName]\Contributors" ALLOW /collection:$collection
```

However, I also want them to be able to change the default team's iteration settings as well (changing the default iteration, what's in the Backlogs hub, etc.) and I can't find how to do that. Does anyone know what I can run in TfsSecurity to grant this access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure `the default team's settings`, you must either be a `team administrator` or a `project administrator`.

So, you need to add the `Contributors group` to `team administrator` or a `project administrator` group.

eg:

```
tfssecurity /g+ "[ProjectName]\Project Administrators" "n:[ProjectName]\Contributors" /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/
```

[image]

Comment: The way I understand your question is that it's not possible to do what I want. I want to give contributors this access without giving them admin access. So I gave up to trying to do that and we now just have admins do the work that we wanted contributors to be able to do.